# Standard practice in formatting HTML tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple table in an HTML page. Nothing special.
The format is as follows:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    
+Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + Col5 + Col6+  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
+     +      +      +      +      +     +  
+     +      +      +      +      +     +  
+     +      +      +      +      +     +  
+     +      +      +      +      +     +  
+     +      +      +      +      +     +  
+     +      +      +      +      +     +  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

All the rows display text but I have the following problem:
If the contents in a row of Col6 are too big, then the row "expands" in 2 lines to fit the contents for that row and as a result the text in other column breaks in 2 lines.
E.g. if `Col2` had the text: `Some-text-in-here` it becomes:
`Some-text`
`in-here`
And I don't want that.

How do we solve this issue with arrays so that each column does not get affect by the size of other columns this way?

Comment: Have you tried assigning widths to your columns?

Comment: Can't you just explicitly set the width of the columns? Edit: Scooped!

Comment: @MikeRobinson:How do I know what width to put? Isn't this related to resolution/browser etc?

Comment: @MikeCole:Same comment as above

Comment: @Matt Coughlin:Why did you remove your answer???????I needed it and was about to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table-layout: fixed` for table in combination with some explicit table width (e.g. `width: 100%`) to make table cell's widths independent from content width.

You can use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent line wrapping in an element.

Comment: The line that is wrapping for me does not have any whitespace.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` prevents line wrapping regardless of property-name meaning and/or your understanding of it. Browsers do wrap lines at dash positions too, not just at whitespace characters.

Comment: Really? So a `-` can be used to wrap arround a line much like a space?

Comment: Exactly. Don't hesitate to try it on your own. ;-)

Comment: So how is `white-space` related to `table-layout`? I mean is it one or the other what you propose?

Comment: I have described purpose of each of the two properties quite clearly. To achieve one of goals, use a corresponding property from the two. To achieve both goals, use both properties. What exactly is not clear enough for you?